# How to use (or simulate) object spread with overriding fields in Flow?

Tags: javascript, typescript, flowtype

This doesn't compile on the "Try Flow":

```
/* @flow */

type A = { a: number, b: string};
type B = { a: string, b: string };

const x: A = { a:1, b:'2' };
const y: B = { ...x, a: x.a.toString() }
```

Error is:

```
const y: B = { ...x, a: x.a.toString() }
                ^ Cannot assign object literal to `y` because number [1] is incompatible with string [2] in property `a`.

    References:

    3: type A = { a: number, b: string};
                     ^ [1]

    4: type B = { a: string, b: string };
                     ^ [2]
```

Note that this code works in TypeScript (when I remove field override it fails to compile as it is supposed to).

**How to achieve same behavior in Flow without enumerating all fields of original object?**

Answer (score 3):

Some major improvements to spreads are coming out in Flow v0.111.0, scheduled for release next week. This snippet will now typecheck. You can see it in action now in [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCYAvGAN5gCGAXGAHYCuAtgEZ4BOANGK3QM4YOAS3oBzAL4BuTLgIAhUhWoChosTz5hBI8WGnoAxnHqCwADzrEylWgEZNNAOQAmJ-pnHTGMFjqKbMAA6EPMeWgsgqiCMOABlNXEACgBKfSA) by switching to the "master" version.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't do this, and it's a "known" [bug in Flow](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6108). It is "known" but I didn't see any indication that someone is actually working on it.

You can:

- declare `B.a` to be a union of `number | string`.
- declare a mapping function like this:

  ```
  const mapfn = ({ a, ...rest }: A): B => ({ ...rest, a: a.toString() });

  const x: A = { a: 1, b: '2' };
  const y: B = mapfn(x);
  ```

EDIT: it seems you can now do this with the newest version of Flow. See the above issue for details, they've fixed this bug. Upgrade your Flow!