# flow returns wrong type

Tags: flowtype

I have this piece of code:

```
/* @flow */
import { List } from 'immutable';

type NotMapped = {|
  first: Array<number>,
  second: number,
|};

type Mapped = {|
  first: List<number>,
  second: number,
|};

const notMapped: NotMapped = {
  first: [1, 2, 3],
  second: 10,
};

const map = () => {
  const first = List(notMapped.first);
  return { ...notMapped, first };
}

const result: Mapped = map();
```

I want result to be`Mapped` type but I get:

```
{|
  first: List<number> | Array<number>,
  second: number
|}
```

How come that flow thinks it might be `Array<number>` when I explicitly set `first` as `List(notMapped.first)`? It only works if I set `return { second: notMapped.second, first };`, but this isn't a solution because I have large amount of data and I cannot set every item. 
I have checked and this is well-known issue, but when spreading types, not object with assigned type. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I believe the issues permeate to objects with assigned types because Flow still has to spread the types of the objects. See issues [#7767](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7767), [#7616](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7616), and [#6108](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6108), and PR [#7298](https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/7298) for more info. Jordan Brown, developer on Flow, is [working on this](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7767#issuecomment-497036413) currently.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52924531/how-to-use-or-simulate-object-spread-with-overriding-fields-in-flow.